# RNG validator supporting xi:include

Tags: java, xml, schema

I need to validate xml files against a RNG shema.

Those xml files may use other xml files through elements <xi:include/>.

Those referenced xml files might not be available at this step of the process.

Is there a java component RNG validator supporting unresolved <xi:include/> ?

By default, those unresolved elements are considered as valid.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very specific to my need :

- documents to check are docBook documents
- The DocBook Team published a relax ng dedicated to documents with xi:include
  : https://docbook.org/xml/5.0/rng/

Then there is no need to do anything at validator level in this case.